# How to host a node react web application on cPanel?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cpanel

I would like to host my Node React web application but I don't find any tutorial, somebody can help me ? Thx

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/49939601/6727154

Comment: I tried but it doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your react app is  client side version only you can just copy the production build in public folder.. But if your react app is inside a node server(Server Side Rendering), you need to install node in your host.