# How to run Frontity project on cPanel?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, cpanel, frontity

I have purchased a web domain and a web hosting that contains its own cPanel. I have also build my Frontity project as well. I also made sure that my web hosting supports Node.js. After updating the node and npm versions to match my machine that develops the web app, I then followed these steps to try and get the web hosting to work:

1. I ensured that my package.json contains the domain name. ie: `"homepage": "#domainnamehere"`
2. I created the build file using `npx frontity build`. This produces the `build` directory which contains the `static` folder and `server.js` file. I then zipped both files under a zip file called `build.zip`
3. I uploaded the `build.zip` file to cPanel, in which I extracted its contents inside the /public_html directory within cPanel.
4. I then cd into my build folder, and ran `npx frontity serve` to run the website, as suggested by moderator juanma in this [deployment for Frontity topic](https://community.frontity.org/t/how-can-i-deploy-frontity-to-a-hosting-with-cpanel/2525). However, on my screen, it just shows "403 Forbidden Access to this resource on the server is denied."
5. I then created a `.htaccess` at at the /public_html directory, using [Finoy Francis's answer at Step 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49939601/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-on-cpanel) for routing.

> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteBase /
> RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
> RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
> </IfModule>
> ```

However it still shows the same 403 Forbidden Access error.

What steps should I take from this point forward?